# How to integrate 7 segment display with ULN2003?

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, communication

I am working on a project. A water level indicator using ULN2003. Now I want to integrate a 7 segment display to indicate the water level. How?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to the electronics SE (electronics.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you have a micro controller driving the ULN2003. How about the following sketch.

[image: connecting 7 segment display to ULN2003]

This show how to connect the segments and provide power to the display.

Following chart has some guidelines on how to drive the 7 segment display.

[image: 7 segment display drive signals]

These should get you started.